# Mapping over a Seq to filter

Tags: scala

I have a Seq[Document].

Document has a val field which is a String such that one can do

```
d.typ   ---> which will be a String
```

I would like to map and filter over the Seq to produce a new Seq of only those Documents whose typ field is equal to a particular string. So far I have this:

```
def getNewProducts(docs: Seq[Document]):Seq[Document] = {

   docs.map(_.typ == "new-product")

}
```

I understand that I need to provide a predicate filter to the map function but not how to do it. All thanks gratefully received.

Comment: If you truly need to both `map` and `filter` then `collect` is what you want. It takes a `PartialFunction` (typically match-block-like partial function literal). The filtering is based on the inputs for which the partial function is defined and the mapping is based on what the result of those cases are.

Comment: Looks like you only want to filter, not map. Mapping means that you transform each element of a collection to something different, so you get a collection of transformed elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for this?

```
docs.filter(_.typ == "new-product")
```